# Packaging same code for using in different contexts

Tags: c#, automation

My work involved creating various tools and utilities for in-house use for automation purposes.

Some of my actions are packed all together in one DLL file.

This DLL is then wrapped in another DLL for use from within 1 automation tool, while it is packed in another DLL to be used in another tool (for example -- FinalBuilder).

It is then repackaged as an Executable for running as a standalone tool.

My question is -- did anyone encounter any scenario like this, where multiple small "actions" or utilities need to be reused in various contexts (finalbuilder, standalone, etc) ?

If so, is there any easier option to be able to define these once and be able to use them in various locations, instead of writing additional wrappers all the time ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand the need to "wrap" your shared code dll in another dll.

If your code is shareable, then it should be in a library (with its own namespace(s)). Any number of applications can link to (reference) this library. To deploy the applications, they will all just need a copy of the library assembly next to their .exe file - no wrapping required.

If you wish your .exes to be single files with no additional dlls, then you can use a utility like [ILMerge](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=22914587-b4ad-4eae-87cf-b14ae6a939b0&displaylang=en) to merge the assemblies together to form a single coherent binary.

A last option is to make multiple csharp projects that share the same source code, so you simply "include" the shared code into all your .exe projects. This would mean you build a single .exe without any need to ship extra dlls or use ILMerge to merge the assemblies after compiling. The down side of this is just that you have to build all the library code every time you build your .exe, so your builds will probably be slower. (And whatever you do, don't make multiple *copies* of the source code - if you wish to update the shared library it is essential that there is only *one master copy* of all the source code)

Comment: ILMerge is exactly what i wanted!

Comment: Regarding your last suggestion - i find it hard to manage this scenario where i have multiple projects all with the same code opened in them. One change in a shared file might be breaking the other projects as well... is that what u mean by "make your builds slower"?